# Error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB" in Join Statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, ora-00932

I have problem executing below stored procedure.
I am getting error of `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB` when I add
`FM.FAXFILE_BLOB` column in below stored procedure.`FAXFILE_BLOB` is a blob field.
If I remove this field everything works fine.I don't know why this is happening.
Please help....

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure HCADMIN.Proc_GetFaxDetailsByDate
         ( 
           FromDate varchar2 default null,
           ToDate varchar2 default null,
           FaxNo varchar2 default null,
           ClaimNo varchar2 default null,
            NspCode varchar2 default null,
           PolicyNo varchar2 default null,
           HEGICNo varchar2 default null,
           cur_faxdetails OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
           )
        IS
       BEGIN
      OPEN cur_faxdetails For

      Select distinct
       FM.RECORDNO_NUM,
       FM.CLAIMNO_VAR,
       FM.FAXNO_VAR,
       FM.FAXSTATUS_VAR,
       FM.FAXTYPE_VAR,
       FM.USERNAME_VAR,
       FM.HEGIC_NO_VAR, 
       FM.RESEND_NO_NUM,
       FM.RESNDCOUNT_NUM,
       TO_date(FM.TIMESTAMP_DTE,'dd/MM/yyyy') as "TIMESTAMP_DTE",
       FR.RECIPIENTFAXNO_VAR,
       FM.FAXFILE_BLOB

       From TPA_FAXMASTER FM Left  join TPA_FAXRECIPIENT FR on                                      FM.RECORDNO_NUM=FR.RECORDNO_NUM 
 WHERE 
      NVL(FM.FAXNO_VAR,'0')=NVL(FaxNo,NVL(FM.FAXNO_VAR,'0')) And
      NVL(FR.RECIPIENTFAXNO_VAR,'0')=NVL(FaxNo,NVL(FR.RECIPIENTFAXNO_VAR,'0')) And          
      NVL(FM.CLAIMNO_VAR,'0')=NVL(ClaimNo,NVL(FM.CLAIMNO_VAR,'0')) And  
      NVL(FM.NSPID_VAR,'0')=NVL(NspCode,NVL(FM.NSPID_VAR,'0')) And
      NVL(FM.POLICYNO_VAR,'0')=NVL(PolicyNo,NVL(FM.POLICYNO_VAR,'0')) And  
      NVL(FM.HEGIC_NO_VAR,'0')=NVL(HEGICNo,NVL(FM.HEGIC_NO_VAR,'0')) And    
      (NVL(TO_date(FM.TIMESTAMP_DTE,'dd/MM/yyy'),To_Date('09/09/9999','dd/MM/yyyy')) 
      BETWEEN NVL (TO_date(FromDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'), NVL(TO_date(FM.TIMESTAMP_DTE,'dd/MM/yyy'),To_Date('09/09/9999','dd/MM/yyyy')))
      AND  NVL (TO_date(ToDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'), NVL(TO_date(FM.TIMESTAMP_DTE,'dd/MM/yyy'),To_Date('09/09/9999','dd/MM/yyyy'))));
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   Null;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE;
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot specify [DISTINCT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2065646) if the select_list contains LOB columns.

Try to use a scalar subquery to get the BLOB field.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. But why is this so?

Comment: There are some restrictions on LOBs. Probably it's because they're stored in a different way from basic data-types. To go deeper on it refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_working.htm#i1006278 and to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm#i1000000

Answer (score 3):

Below restrictions are applied on the set operators.

> The set operators are subject to the following restrictions:
>
> **The set operators are not valid on columns of type BLOB, CLOB, BFILE,
>   VARRAY, or nested table.**
>
> The UNION, INTERSECT, and MINUS operators are not valid on LONG
>   columns.
>
> If the select list preceding the set operator contains an expression,
>   then you must provide a column alias for the expression in order to
>   refer to it in the order_by_clause.
>
> You cannot also specify the for_update_clause with the set operators.
>
> You cannot specify the order_by_clause in the subquery of these
>   operators.
>
> You cannot use these operators in SELECT statements containing TABLE
>   collection expressions.

Reference [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm).